# How to get the sum of the foreach loop?

Tags: php

I have a foreach loop problem where I think something is wrong with my logic. The data from table will be subtracted from the payment amount, if the payment amount is 0 it will stop the loop.

PHP 5

```
$payment_amount_pay = 5000;

foreach ($data as $value) {

    $amount = $value['AMOUNT'];

    $payment_amount_pay = $payment_amount_pay - $amount;


    echo $payment_amount_pay;

}
```

this data from my table

```
2000
15000
3000
```

i always get this output

```
3000
-12000
-15000
```

This should be the correct output.

```
-2000
-3000
```

Comment: Can you please make it more clear what do you want? Correct output you wrote doesn't look correct as per your table entries and the code you are running. How are assuming the correct output should be what you wrote?

Comment: I think some more information is needed here. For instance, is $value a single value or a collection as you have indicated. with $value['AMOUNT']?

Comment: just from the first iteration 5000-2000=3000, how can -2000 be correct?

Comment: `$payment_amount_pay = $payment_amount_pay - $value['AMOUNT'];` 

After you minus payment_amount_pay, you input to `$payment_amount_pay`. So, `$payment_amount_pay` value is override.

Comment: You declared `$amount = $value['AMOUNT'];` and yet you just used the raw data `$payment_amount_pay = $payment_amount_pay - $value['AMOUNT'];`

Comment: @SatishSaini Hi sir, the data from table will be subtracted with the payment amount if the payment_amount will be 0 it will stop the loop.

Comment: Can you try to show example? How to be -2000 and -3000 result?

Comment: @SuYatanar base on the data from the table, the payment amount will be substracted on the amount and will continue to subtract until the amount will be 0.

Comment: I don't see what is wrong with your output data, `5000-2000=3000; 3000-15000=-12000; -12000-3000=-15000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want want it to be something like this?

```
$payment_amount_pay = 5000;

foreach ($data as $value) {

    // Check if the amount already used up
    if($payment_amount_pay < 0) {
        break;
    }

    $amount = $value['AMOUNT'];

    // Get the differences
    $payment_amount_pay = $payment_amount_pay - $amount;

    if($payment_amount_pay >= 0) {
        // Changed to negative (not sure why you need it)
        echo 0  - $amount."<br>";
    }
    else {
        // Changed to negative (not sure why you need it)
        echo 0  - $payment_amount_pay - $amount."<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: HI, the answer was correct, but i have 
clarification. would you mind if i can ask some clarification.

Comment: Sure. Feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you try to achieve is this

```
   $payment_amount_pay = 5000;

foreach ($data as $value) {

    $amount = $value['AMOUNT'];
If ($payment_amount_pay -= amount > 0){
    $payment_amount_pay = $payment_amount_pay - $amount;}


    echo “-“.$amount;

}
```

Comment: hmm something like that, if i have 5,000 amount. the amount will be subtracted on the table's data. like I've shown above.

Comment: Your mistake was that you needed an if statement with a check if the payment amount minus the amount of the table would be higher or lower than 0 :) you should only do the substraction if the check returnes true

Answer (score 0):

**2000, 15000, 3000** I think this amount are represent for `$value['AMOUNT']`;

```
$payment_amount_pay = 5000;

    foreach ($data as $value) {

        $amount = $value['AMOUNT'];

        $payment_amount_pay = $payment_amount_pay - $amount;

        // first loop => 3000  = 5000 - 2000;  3000 will be $payment_amount_pay
        // second loop => -12000  = 3000 - 15000; -12000 will be $payment_amount_pay
        // third loop =>  -15000  = -12000 - 3000; -15000 will be $payment_amount_pay

        echo $payment_amount_pay;

    }
```

How to be -2000 and -3000?

Comment: hmmm for example: if i have 2,000, 15, 000 from my table, and i have 5,000 of the payment, the payment will be subtracted on the 2,000 and the remaining will the remaining.